# MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET of Mac OS X binary file

Tags: macos, binaryfiles

Is it possible to read from binary what was the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET parameter when binary was compiled?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to look for `LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX` load command in Mach-O view header. However, it was added only in 10.8 and it may not exist on binaries built in previous versions of Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

If you explore the application, by right clicking on the application icon, then selecting "Show Package Contents". Then open up the "Contents" folder. Then open up the MacOS folder and right click on the executable. Chose "get info" and then read what it says for "Created". I think that should do it.

Comment: It's a date, isn't it? I'm looking for something like "10.6", "10.7", etc. I doubt that info is public. However I hope it should exist somewhere in Mach-O header.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand your question. For this you need to show the package contents of the application, as above, and double click on the "Info.Plist" file. Then look at the left column for "Minimum system version".

Comment: It does for app. However, I need the solution for binaries. E.g. for dylib libraries or command line utilities.

Comment: Well, good question. I've done a little more research on the mac binary structure, and then I thought I'd do a "hexdump" on some software I've written for my mac. Hmmm, I'm scratching my head on this one right now.

Comment: Hey, does [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html) help any?